# Getting extended property from Exchange/Outlook appointment

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I add an extended property in this way:

```
ExtendedPropertyDefinition ep = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.CalendarAssistant, "AppointmentID", MapiPropertyType.Integer);
Appointment newApp = new Appointment(service);
newapp.SetExtendedProperty(ep, appID);
newApp.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
```

All is good.  The appointment shows up in Outlook as expected.

Later I tried to search through all Outlook appointment with an AppointmentID assigned by:

```
List<SearchFilter> filters = new List<SearchFilter>();
filters.Add(new SearchFilter.Exists(ep));
filters.Add(new SearchFilter.IsLessThan(AppointmentSchema.Start, DateTime.Now.AddDays(60)));
filters.Add(new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(AppointmentSchema.Start, DateTime.Today));
FindItemsResults<Item> allOutlookAppt = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, filters.ToArray()), viewFind);
```

allOutlookAppt returns the expected collection (calendar entries with AppointmentID set).  However I could not retrieve the AppointmentID by this code:

```
foreach (var a in allOutlookAppt) // contains correct calendar entries!
{
    object oid;
    if (a.TryGetProperty(ep, out oid))
    {
    // a.TryGetProperty is always false, oid is always null thus never enter here!
    }
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Edit: I tried a.ExtendedProperties.Count and it actually returns 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling a bit I have to add this before searching the calendar

```
viewFind.PropertySet = new PropertySet(ep);
```